# Trigger working fine, but the insertion is wrong

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have the following trigger in a table:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trReportInsertLog

AFTER INSERT ON repport_table

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE last_id int;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO last_id;

INSERT INTO systemlog_table (Id, Description)
VALUES ('', 'Created a new Report with Id = '+last_id); /* PROBLEM HERE */

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem I have, is when I insert the values.
The first value is empty because it's an auto_increment column. (working fine)

The other value is a string, but only the 'last_id' is inserted.

I think it's maybe the quotations that is wrong. I have tried multiple ways, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: try: **VALUES ('', CONCAT('Created a new Report with Id = ',last_id));**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `systemlog_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `repport_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `repport_table` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `current_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `systemlog_table` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trReportInsertLog`$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trReportInsertLog` AFTER INSERT ON `repport_table`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     /*
   /*>     DECLARE last_id int;
   /*>     SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO last_id;
   /*> 
   /*>     INSERT INTO systemlog_table (Id, Description)
   /*>     VALUES ('', 'Created a new Report with Id = '+last_id); /* PROBLEM HERE *\/
   /*>     */
    -> 
    ->     INSERT INTO `systemlog_table` (`description`)
    ->     VALUES (CONCAT('Created a new Report with Id = ', NEW.`id`));
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> INSERT INTO `repport_table` (`current_at`)
    -> VALUES (NOW());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `current_at`
    -> FROM `repport_table`;
+----+---------------------+
| id | current_at          |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:01 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `description`
    -> FROM `systemlog_table`;
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | description                      |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Created a new Report with Id = 1 |
+----+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```